Apache rotatelogs
Пытался настроить в Апаче ротацию логов через модуль rotatelogs. Изменил в конфиге директиву CustomLog по аналогии с документацией на сайте.

но логику алгоритма понять не могу. Хоть и создался новый файл лога, но как видно из даты изменения Апач продолжает писать и в старый файл лога, который уже несколько гигов, и в новый.

Что я не правильно настроил? Почему логи пишутся в оба файла? Могу ли я безболезненно удалить изначальный файл, который уже достиг 14ГБ?
